# Longest Sequence in array with matching last and first character

Tags: java, arrays

I recently was asked a question to create a sequence from an array of string such that the string elements can combine if the last character of element 1 matches the first character of element 2.

Eg: {"ab", "bc", "cd", "ad", "def", "cedd"} should return "**abceddef**".

What I'm getting for above input is "**abcdef**".

```
public class LongestSubstringConsecutiveEnds {

    static StringBuilder sbMax = new StringBuilder();
    static StringBuilder sbTemp;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] inputStrings = {"ab", "bc", "cd", "ad", "def", "cedd"};
        List<String> inputList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(inputStrings));

        for(int i=0; i<inputList.size(); i++) {

            String str = inputList.get(i);
            sbTemp = new StringBuilder(str);
            inputList.remove(str);
            longestSequence(sbTemp, new ArrayList<String>(inputList));
            inputList.add(0, str);
        }

        System.out.println(sbMax.toString());
    }

    private static void longestSequence(StringBuilder tempSubstring, final List<String> inputList) {

        System.out.println(tempSubstring.toString() + inputList);
        if(tempSubstring.length() > sbMax.length()) {
            sbMax.delete(0, sbMax.length());
            sbMax.append(tempSubstring);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<inputList.size(); i++) {

            String inputListString = inputList.get(i);
            char tempStrLastChar = tempSubstring.charAt(tempSubstring.length()-1);
            if(inputListString.charAt(0) == tempStrLastChar) {

                String str = inputList.remove(i);
                longestSequence(tempSubstring.append(inputListString.substring(1)), inputList);
                inputList.add(i, str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show what you've done so far to try to solve this problem.

Comment: And what was your answer? Do you think it's wrong? Why?

Comment: cool interview question, show us what you have tried...

Comment: What I'm getting for above input is abcdef

Comment: That info should also be in your question.

Comment: Can you explain how "abceddef" is correct. I think there is something missing

Comment: "abbccedddef" should be the answer. if i understood you question correctly. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Jabir, when the last character of element 1 matches the first character of element 2, that character to be used once in the sequence. So, if you have "ab" and "bc" then the output string should be "abc" and not "abbc".

Answer (score 0):

According your question:

> if the last character of element 1 matches the first character of element 2.

Part you described in your question can be done easy:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length - 1; i++) {
    //   last char of element i         is equal     first char of element i+1                  
    if (strings[i].charAt(strings[i].length()-1) == strings[i+1].charAt(0)) {
        // print element i.
        System.out.print(strings[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

> cd

That is, position 3 matches with 4 (c**d**-**d**ef)

But that does not match with

> should return "abceddef"
>   And I can't find a logic... where last **ef** comes from? you mean match when for example last is **a** and first is **b** ??. That would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length - 1; i++) {
    // get last and first char
    String actual = strings[i];
    char last  = actual.charAt(actual.length()-1);
    char first = strings[i+1].charAt(0);

    if ((int) first == last + 1) {
        System.out.print(actual);
    }
}
```

Output:

> ab

That is, position 2 matches with 3 (a**b**-**c**d)

Comment: How is this an answer

Comment: @Jordi, I don't think the solution you have given is gonna work.

Comment: Both codes works, but are them doing the correct thing? I cant know because you dont tell us clearly what you want to do,. Read the comments and provide a real question with coherent example output

Comment: @JordiCastilla, The information is there in the question. You need to create the longest sequence that can be formed from array of strings such that ending character of first string should be first character of next string and the common character should appear only once.

Comment: Nono... Info is not in the question...my 2nd option does that bt not longest.... What is common character for you? In your solution... Where the f of your sollution comes from if the array does notn contain any?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String...args){
    final String[] input={"ab", "bc", "cd", "ad", "def", "cedd"};
    System.out.println( funkyConcat(input));
}
private static String funkyConcat(String...strings){
    String ret="";
    for(String i:strings){
        if(ret.isEmpty()){
            ret=i;
        }else if(ret.substring(ret.length()-1).equals(i.substring(0,1))){
            ret+=i.substring(1);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: your output: `abcdef` expected output: `abceddef` sorry dude but I can't find logic either... xDDDD

Comment: The solution will employ backtracking... But I'm not sure about the base condition and looping I'm using in my solution. The approach I've used is partially correct but it is not tracking all the permutation and combination cases.